# Theorem about series of functions

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, solution-verification, sequence-of-function

> If both series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_{\mathrm{n}}(x)$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_{\mathrm{n}}^{\prime}(x)$ converge uniformly on I and $f_{n}^{\prime}$ is continuous for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then the function $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_{n}(x)$ is differantiable on I and we have $f^{\prime}(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_{n}^{\prime}(x)$

**My Work:**

We want to prove that $f^{\prime}(x) =\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_{n}^{\prime}(x)$ in other words $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} f_{n}(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_{n}(x)$ we know that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_{n}(x)$ converge uniformly. Then $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}f_{n}(x)=f(x)$ exist. Also we can say that from the information given in question, $f_{n}$ is differantiable because $f_{n}^{\prime}$ is continuos.

And from above we can say that $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}f_{n}^{\prime}=f^{\prime}$ since $f_{n}^{\prime}$ is continuous. Therefore, that is, $f^{\prime}=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_{n}^{\prime}$.

Does it sufficient to prove? I am not sure...

Comment: What theorem are you using to say that $f_n' \to f'$? Where is the proof that $f$ is differentiable?

Comment: For the record, $f_n'$ being continuous is irrelevant for the purpose of establishing that $f_n$ is differentiable.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy $f^{\prime}$ continuous. Is this property sufficient?

Comment: You begin with “We want to prove that $f(x) =\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_{n}(x)$”. No, we don't. That's how $f(x)$ is defined. Then you say “in other words $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} f_{n}(x) =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_{n}(x)$”. This doesn't even make sense.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos edited

Comment: It is not given that $f'$ is continuous. It is not even given that $f'$ exists.

Comment: $\lim_{n \to \infty} f'_n = f'$, even if true, would certainly not imply $f' = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n'$. Convergence of the latter implies $\lim_{n \to \infty}f'_n = 0$.

Comment: I still the nonsense $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} f_{n}(x) =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_{n}(x)$ there.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} f_{n}(x)=f(x)$. Isn't it?

Comment: @beingmathematician It says right in the question that $f(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}f_n(x)$, not $f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x)$. These are not the same!

Comment: No, it is not. What we have is $\displaystyle f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$,

Comment: Oh now I see... Okay I understand

Comment: Evaluate $f'$ from its definition as a limit.

Answer (score 2):

You said nothing about $I$. I will assume that it is an interval of $\Bbb R$.

For each $N\in\Bbb N$, let $F_N=\sum_{n=1}^Nf_n$. Then$$F_N'=\left(\sum_{n=1}^Nf_n\right)'=\sum_{n=1}^Nf_n'$$and the goal is to prove that $\lim_{N\to\infty}F_N$ is differentiable and that$$\left(\lim_{N\to\infty}F_N\right)'=\lim_{N\to\infty}F_N'.\tag1$$

Since each $F_N'$ is continuous, it is Riemann-integrable on any interval $[a,b]\subset I$. Fix $a\in I$. Then$$F_N(x)=F_N(a)+\int_a^xF_N'(t)\,\mathrm dt.$$Since $(F_N')_{N\in\Bbb N}$ converges uniformly on $I$, it converges uniformly on each subinterval of $I$, and therefore\begin{align}\lim_{N\to\infty}F_N(x)&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\left(F_N(a)+\int_a^xF_N'(t)\,\mathrm dt\right)\\&=\lim_{N\to\infty}F_N(a)+\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_a^xF_N'(t)\,\mathrm dt\\&=\lim_{N\to\infty}F_N(a)+\int_a^x\lim_{N\to\infty}F_N'(t)\,\mathrm dt,\end{align}since the convergence is uniform. Therefore, by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, $(1)$ holds.

Comment: (+1) I fixed a few typos, apologies if not what you intended.

Comment: Interesting to observe that uniform convergence of $\sum f_n$ does not appear to be required, and in fact all your proof needs is convergence of $\sum f_n(x)$ at the single point $x=a$.

Comment: @Bungo Thank you for editing. And, indeed, only the uniform convergence of $\sum f_n'$ is required.

Comment: Sorry, I did not look up for a while, I was in exam. Thanks a lot!